# PHP append random number if value have only 1 number

Tags: php, random

I am using a code to view the TMDB movie rating
generally the rating of the movie is 3 characters for example: **7.4** but, many times the rating is only one character like for example 6.

I should add the value .4 or a random number with the dot only if the number is single and doesn't have 3 characters.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What EXACTLY is the problem?

Comment: I am using a code on wordpress for the progress bar, the problem is that I need a multiple and not a single number I have to add a random number immediately after the single value, I haven't tried anything yet I don't know where to start

Comment: So basically you're looking for a way to present 6 as 6.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend just appending `'.0'` to the number when it only has a length of 1.

```php
function getRating($value){
  return $value . (strlen($value) === 1 ? '.0': '');
}
```

But, if you must randomise it:

```php
function getRating($value){
  return $value . (strlen($value) === 1 ? '.'.rand(0,9): '');
}
```

Comment: im using this code how to ad your function inside?   function ProgressBar() {  
global $post; 
$vote_average = esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID,'vote_average', true));
$progress = str_replace(".", "", $vote_average);
$count = $progress;
if ($count >= 0 && $count < 50) {
    echo 'danger';
} elseif ($count < 70) {
    echo '';
} elseif ($count < 80) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'success';
}
}

Comment: add it below/outside of your current function and call it inside where you need it.